# Erro ao adicionar botão no admin do wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um plugin para wordpress e quando uso orientação a objetos para adicionar um botão na seção de postagens ele me exibe o seguinte erro:

> "Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'add_media_button' not found or invalid function
>   name in /var/www/jovempan/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286"

OBS: Esse erro só aparece quando uso POO

Meu código:

```
class PostagensRelacionadas{
   public function __construct(){
      add_action('media_buttons', 'add_media_button');
   }

   public function add_media_button() {
      $dados = printf( ' <a href="#TB_inline?&width=600&height=550&inlineId=my-content-id" class="button my-button my-custom-button" id="my-custom-button">' . '<span class="wp-media-buttons-icon dashicons dashicons-art"></span> %s' . '</a>', 'Notícias Relacionadas', __( 'Notícias relacionadas', 'textdomain' ) );
   }
}

$class = new PostagensRelacionadas();
$class->add_media_button();
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja, já que você está em uma classe, deve passar a mesma, junto do nome da função como parâmetro em `add_action`:

```
public function __construct(){
  add_action('media_buttons', array($this,'add_media_button'));
}
```

Dessa forma, o `$this` representa a classe atual, e `add_media_button`, a função dela.

Dê uma olhada na documentação sobre [Callbacks](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.callable.php). Para uma boa introdução à plugins orientados a objetos, existe um "esqueleto" muito útil, o [Wordpress Plugin Boilerplate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate)